# Can PHP code be used without permission?

Tags: open-source-software

I am using PHP code to make a website.

Can anybody can use my PHP code without my permission because of open source?

Answer (score 4):

PHP is open source, anyone can use it. Your code in PHP is your copyright, you decide who can use it.

This is just like: English is open source, anyone can use it. Your novel in English is your copyright, you decide who can use it.

Comment: satisfied very much, specially your example